# How to track if Error Message was presented during Installing or how to block Ignore option when Error occurs?

Tags: error-handling, inno-setup

When installing we can encounter an error message announcing faulty BIN, faulty File Sha, Not Enough Space, etc.

By default there are Retry/Ignore/Abort options to choose from.

If user chooses Ignore, how to inform him on the wpFinished, that there were some errors during installation process noticed?

Or how to Hide Ignore Button on the Error MsgBox?

Comment: It seems that changing `AbortRetryIgnoreMsgBox` or tracing the `AbortRetryIgnoreMsgBox`/`NoErrorMessages` triggering could be the case. But I am unable to achieve that.

Comment: That is not impossible, but you would need an external library to hook underlying `MessageBox` Windows API function calls. From such library you would then expose a function to register a callback to your script which you would call whenever your patched function was called (actually a notification about a just displayed message box). Oh, and that's not all because even when you hook the message box, you still need to know what that message box tells and thus you need to parse its text to distinguish e.g. between failures and a query if the user wants to exit the setup. Which is, ehm, crappy.

Comment: Similar level of reliability you achieve if you parse the installation log (not sure if it's available at that time though). The best would be to have some collection of errors that occurred during the whole installation process (filterable by severity, error type and error source). Some sort of filterable log accessible from script. But that of course requires modifications of Inno Setup...

Comment: Pity, that it is not possible to track wpInstalling errors in IS. Hope that it will be implemented in future version.

Comment: I would be for event like `OnFilesEntryProcessed` or something like that which would be fired for every entry right after its processing (reporting result of processing) and put there also the ability to cancel (rollback) the setup. Btw. the progress bar state changes can be traced quite easily but requires Vista above system...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to track an error when Retry/Ignore/Abort ocuurs while installing.

```
 //Global vars

   var SetupDone: Boolean; //by default must be False
       StepInstalling: Boolean; //by default must be False

 //code

  procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
   var
    ResultCode: Integer;
     begin
      case CurStep of    
       ssInstall:
        begin
         // .... some code
         StepInstalling:=True;
        end; 
       ssDone:
        begin
         SetupDone:=True;
        end;
       end;
      end;

  procedure HandleTerminateRetryCancelErrorWhileInstalling();
   begin
    // some code to do when error occurs
   end; 

  procedure DeinitializeSetup();
   begin                           
    If ((SetupDone <> True) and (StepInstalling = True)) then    
     begin  
      MsgBox('Handling', mbconfirmation, mb_OK);
      HandleTerminateRetryCancelErrorWhileInstalling();
     end;
    end;
```